# utf-8 character input fail to PHP regex

Tags: php, regex, html

```
  <?php
        if(isset($_GET['textvalue'])){
            $string = $_GET['textvalue']; //preg_match return false
            //$string = '한자漢字メ'; //preg_match return true
            $stringArray = preg_match('/^[\p{L}]{2,30}$/u', $string);
        }

    ?>



<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <form method="GET">
            <input type="text" name="textvalue">
            <input type="submit">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

I'm trying to regex the value from the input.
Unfortunately, every time I submit the characters, `preg_match` return `false`. But, if I use the string from the variable, it'll return `true`.

What going on and how do I fix it?

Comment: You should output your $_GET. It might be urlencoded (if you are lucky). Usually you should submit these values via POST method.

Comment: There might be spaces - did you use `trim()` for instance? Please share your `$_GET` output with us.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone ran into this problem, I've found it. You just need to add this meta header:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
```

I'm not sure why, but with out the codes above, html it send the values to php as a non-utf-8 value. So, then the preg_match try to read it, its reading a different value then what was typed in, thus; it return false.

That's why it work when you just uses the string. HTml is not involved.

note. Even if you try to read by echoing it out, html with return it to its orginal utf-8 value. weird.

Example:

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['textvalue'])){
    $string = $_GET['textvalue']; //preg_match return false
    //$string = '한자漢字メ'; //preg_match return true
    $stringArray = preg_match('/^[\p{L}]{2,30}$/u', $string);
}    
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <head>
    <body>
        <form method="GET">
            <input type="text" name="textvalue">
            <input type="submit">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```